# How I can remove blue line in magnific-popup.js or css when next button clicked?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using bootstrap also, maybe it is cause of it? There are no blue colors in magnific css and there are no colors or #color in the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect your DOM (i use Chrome to do that https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) and select the element appearing with the blue color. You can view the CSS apply on the element and where it comes.